# Update a large set of documents

Tags: couchdb

Is there any way in couchdb to update all documents matching certain conditions? (e.g. create new fields and set values to something based on other data in the document)

I realize that if "new" data can be functionally derived from existing data, then technically you can accomplish this via new views w/o changing the documents, but I need to update a few thousand documents with essentially the same operation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the bulk docs api:
http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API
but you will need to have all the docs first, and submit them back.

or a doc update handler: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers but you at least need to know a list of doc ids, and do one request per id.

Either way, there is nothing like sql where you can issue an update/where statement.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: This link  http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API does not seem to show what you are alluding to.

Just in case someone is stuck like me. I used Arc or Postman if you prefer. First do a `GET /{database_name}/_all_docs;` then when you get documents returned: e.g

```
{
    "total_rows": 7,
     "offset": 0,
      "rows": [
          {
            "id": "16726115a28ba714ce4fddbcf2ce730d",
             "key": "16726115a28ba714ce4fddbcf2ce730d",
             "value": {
                "rev": "1-7d72992fabc85621165b4c0b68b45fac"
                }
            } 
}
```

And then add a line to the data do a POST to /{database_name}/_bulk_docs with the body:

```
{
  "docs": [
    {
      "id": "4b4c709d04483f2b94cbef30cff2430e",
      "key": "4b4c709d04483f2b94cbef30cff2430e",
      "value": {
        "rev": "13-ebd31862b44ad2d4753147d41737d478"
      },
      "_deleted": true
    }
  ]
}
```

You can do the same in any language. Hope it helps someone else.